# Clicking button change text of element jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know its a trivial question but I'm not able to find the right answer.

How to do I change text element by clicking on its parent ?

HTML:

```
<a id="share" class="hithit_button-share">
    <div class="hithit_button-wrapper">
      <div class="hithit_button-label_share absolute second">Share</div>
      <div class="hithit_button-label_share static">Share</div>
    </div>
```

After I click the "a link"  I would love to see the text change to "Copied" on both of the labels?

Thanks

Comment: where is the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".hithit_button-share").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".hithit_button-label_share", this).html("Copied");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="share" class="hithit_button-share">
  <div class="hithit_button-wrapper">
    <div class="hithit_button-label_share absolute second">Share</div>
    <div class="hithit_button-label_share static">Share</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Since you're using a Link, you need to prevent the default event action. You can then Find the elements contained within that element and adjust their Inner HTML.